# Rebuild and keep older .exe

Tags: c++, msbuild, rebuild

I want to build different flavors of my c++ project from the cmd
I'm using msbuild with /p:Varable=Variable and using different folders for each flavor
the problem is every time I rebuild one of the flavors, the .exe file of the last flavor built is erased 
So , there is  way to rebuild with msbuil keeping the othr .exe files
Thank you

Comment: That's what SCM is for. Which VCS are you using? Check out your project into different folders and build with different settings. Or  put the settings into the files you checkout, and make branches for different settings.

Comment: I have already too much configurations, so that's why I'm doing this way
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Copy the executable out of your project directory when you have built it.

msbuild is only trying to maintain integrity within a build: it doesn't know that you are using it in this fashion.

Comment: I tough about it, I just wanted to know if there was an easier and prettier way
Thank you